# Make DIV appear after 'X' amount of radio buttons are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to make a DIV appear after a certain number of radio buttons are selected.

I have it working so it shows up when all of them are selected thanks to individuals inquiring on the similar aspects of this topic, but I was unable to find the code or guidance on my questions.

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$(":radio").change(function() {
    var names = {};
    $(':radio').each(function() {
      names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    });
    var count = 0;
    $.each(names, function() { 
      count++;
    });
    if ($(':radio:checked').length === count) {
      $("#hello").show("400","linear","");
    }
}).change();
});
```

Comment: What's the goal and a "certain number"? Post your HTML as well please.

Comment: I think you already reach what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(':radio:checked').length` is the number of radio buttons that are selected. So just compare this with the number you want.

```
if ($(':radio:checked').length == certain_number) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have what you want working, but you are comparing the number of checked items to the number of total items. I would think it should work if it looked like the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(":radio").change(function() {
        var count = 3; // or whatever number you want
        if ($(':radio:checked').length === count) {
          $("#hello").show("400","linear","");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":radio").change(function() {
  $(":radio").length == $(":radio:checked").length ? $("#hello").show() : null;
});
```

Your intermediate step of creating an array and then counting just to get something that is the length of the number of radios is pointless.

Firing the change event immediately after binding the event handler seems illogical to me.  Are you sure you want that?